# Expectation value of the vector potential operator and the classical limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, photons, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I'm very much a beginner in QFT and am aiming for intuition and basic understanding.

Let's consider a 1D universe and forget about photon polarisation.

Imagine the following quantum state:

$$|\psi\rangle=|n_{k}\rangle$$

an energy eigenstate with $n$ photons with wavenumber $k$.

The expectation value of the vector potential field operator:

$$\hat{A}=\int \frac{dk}{\sqrt{2\omega}}\left(\hat{a}^{-}_{k}e^{i(kz-\omega t)}+\hat{a}^{+}_{k}e^{-i(kz-\omega t)} \right )\tag{1}$$

is

$$\langle\psi|\hat{A}|\psi\rangle=\langle n_{k}|\int \frac{dk}{\sqrt{2\omega}}\left(\hat{a}^{-}_{k}e^{i(kz-\omega t)}+\hat{a}^{+}_{k}e^{-i(kz-\omega t)} \right )|n_{k}\rangle\tag{2}$$

This will be zero because the destruction operators will either create or destroy a photon in the $|n_{k}\rangle$ state so that the projection of the remaining states onto the $\langle n_{k}|$ state is zero.

Question 1:
Why does this even for very high numbers of photons not retrieve the classical limit where one finds a sinusoidal wave?

My best attempt at question 1:

I think this might be a manifestation of $\Delta E\Delta t \geq \hbar$ and the fact that we have here a quantum state for which $\Delta E=0$ so that $\Delta t$ must be infinite and we can infer nothing about the temporal behaviour of the state.

Indeed if we introduce some $\Delta E$ and consider instead the state $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|n_{k}\rangle+|m_{k})\rangle$ we find:

$$\langle\psi|\hat{A}|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\left(\langle n_{k}|+\langle m_{k}|\right)\int \frac{dk}{\sqrt{2\omega}}\left(\hat{a}^{-}_{k}e^{i(kz-\omega t)}+\hat{a}^{+}_{k}e^{-i(kz-\omega t)} \right )\left(|n_{k}\rangle+|m_{k}\rangle\right)\tag{3}$$

Is not zero if $n=m\pm 1$

And will actually give back a real sinusoid since the imaginary part cancels.

Question 2:

Why does this not work with $n=m\pm 2$ which would still give zero?

My poor best attempt at question 2:

Is the state $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|n_{k}\rangle+|(n\pm2)_{k}\rangle)$ unphysical maybe?
Will an $|(n\pm1)_{k}\rangle$ always creep in?

I would love to read any insights!

Answer (score 3):

> Question 1: Why does this even for very high numbers of photons
> not retrieve the classical limit where one finds a sinusoidal wave?

Having a high number of photons is not enough
to make a classical sinusoidal electromagnetic wave.
You need a state which is a superposition of *many
different* numbers of photons.

This is because there is an uncertainty relation
between the number of photons and the phase
(just search for "[number phase uncertainty](https://www.google.de/search?q=number+phase+uncertainty)" to find more info).
$$\Delta n\ \Delta \phi \ge 1$$

A sinusoidal electromagnetic wave has a very precisely defined
phase (i.e. $\Delta\phi \ll 1$).
Therefore the number of photons in this wave is highly uncertain
(i.e. $\Delta n \gg 1$).
So, for building a quasi-classical state
$|\psi\rangle$ you need a sum of many different $|n_k\rangle$
basis states (e.g. with all states from $|n_k=900\rangle$
to $|n_k=1100\rangle$).

Answer (score 0):

The states which have a classical limit are *coherent states* which, for each mode $k$, are of the form $|z\rangle =e^{-|z|^2/2}e^{z \hat a_k^\dagger}|0\rangle$. These have
$$
\hat a_k|z\rangle= z|z\rangle,
$$
and hence
$$
\langle z |\hat a_k|z\rangle = z.
$$